# How to write to files in /var/www (after installing lighttpd)

Tags: permissions, user

I've just successfully installed lighttpd, but I've stumbled at the first stage when trying to create my own HTML file. I try to write to `/var/www` but I get permission denied. I've got a feeling it's to do with the ownership of `/var` (`root:root`), but I don't want to change this as there are plenty of other sub-directories in there besides `www`.

> Ownership:
>   /var root:root
>   /var/www www-data:www-data

My user `pi` is also in the `www-data` group. How can I sort this out?

**Edit**

```
pi@Sun:~$ ls -la /var/www   
total 12   
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 20 19:23 .  
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Jul 20 19:23 ..  
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 3585 Jul 20 19:23 index.lighttpd.html
```

Comment: I've left mine as they are, and use `sudo` to edit files where necessary. Can see that that might be a pain if you're actually coding a site though.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var summarizes it very well.

Comment: Added output from ls -la.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, `www-data` is the owner and owning group of `/var/www`. That doesn't mean anyone in the `www-data` group can write to `/var/www`.

You still need to give them write access:

```
sudo chmod g+w /var/www
```

Comment: Is `www-data` a user or a group?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Both.

Comment: Users are groups - can you add another user to a group which is a user?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: "Users are groups"? This is news to me, or I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you explain what g+w does?

Comment: @MarkIngram: Nothing on its own. I forgot to add `chmod`. Thanks :)